# How to get latitude and longitude of a highway milestone with openstreetmap

Tags: openstreetmap

I need to get the latitude and longitude of a given highway milestone or kilometrical point using openstreetmap Api, I have read the documentation but I can not find an answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How is your "given highway milestone" defined?

Comment: A person type the name or identifier of the road and the kilometrical point. It's for a complex project so we can tell that person how should be typed.

Answer (score 2):

The corresponding OSM [tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) for a highway milestone is [highway=milestone](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag%3ahighway=milestone). It is usually found on [nodes](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Node).

If you know the rough location of the highway milestone then you use the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to retrieve it (note that the [regular API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) is mainly for *editing* map data and should not be used to query it). The required [query](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide) could look like:

```xml
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
    <query type="node">
      <has-kv k="highway" v="milestone"/>
      <bbox-query e="-117.06" n="33.45" s="33.40" w="-117.09"/>
    </query>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

This will retrieve all milestones within the [bounding box](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bounding_box) defined by *e="-117.06" n="33.45" s="33.40" w="-117.09"*. You can [view the result via overpass turbo](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/3fU) which is just a nice webfrontend to the Overpass API.

You can also query for all milestones on/near a specific road:

```xml
<osm-script output="json" timeout="25">
    <query type="way">
      <has-kv k="name" v="Pala Temecula Road"/>
    </query>
    <query type="node">
      <around radius="5"/>
      <has-kv k="highway" v="milestone"/>
    </query>
  <print mode="body"/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
  <print mode="skeleton" order="quadtile"/>
</osm-script>
```

This will retrieve all milestones within a 5 meter radius around the *Pala Temecula Road*.

Note that OSM doesn't include every highway milestone. Currently there are only about [30 000](http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/highway=milestone) highway milestones in OSM, which isn't very much. But [feel free to add more](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Beginners%27_guide).

Comment: And if I wanted to know the milestones for one road instead of using a bounding box?

Comment: I added another example to my answer.